# Pig error in local mode

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to find out the salary in descending order but the output is not correct. I'm running pig in local mode.

My input is as below:

```
a,a@xyz.com,5000

b,b@xyz.com,3000

c,c@xyz.com,10000

a,a1@xyz.com,2000

c,c1@xyz.com,40000

d,d@xyz.com,7000

e,e@xyz.com,1000

f,f@xyz.com,9000

f,f1@xyz.com,110000
```

As I needed **email and salary**(in desc) so here is what I did.

```
A = load '/local_input_path' USING PigStorage(',');

B = foreach A generate $1,$2;

c = ORDER B by $1 DESC;
```

But the output is not as expected:

```
(f@xyz.com,9000)

(d@xyz.com,7000)

(a@xyz.com,5000)

(c1@xyz.com,40000)

(b@xyz.com,3000)

(a1@xyz.com,2000)

(f1@xyz.com,110000)

(c@xyz.com,10000)

(e@xyz.com,1000)
```

When I don't mention `B = foreach A generate $1,$2;` and proceed,output is as expected.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the bytearray into int and then order :

Try this code :

```
a = LOAD '/local_input_path' using PigStorage(',');

b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1,(int)$2;

c = order b by $1 DESC;
dump c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's treating your numbers as strings and performing a lexicographical sort instead of numeric. When you're loading, assign names and types to help prevent this and make your code more readable/maintainable. 
`...USING PigStorage(',') AS (letter:chararray, email:chararray, salary:int)`

Comment: I had even tried that..Unfortunately, result remains same!.Also if it is leading to lexicographical sort, then in second case, where I'm not generating the two fields and performing the operation(taking all the 3 fields), I should get the same result. Right? But it does not happens.